# How to get JWT authentication to work on spring boot 3

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I've been trying to setup spring security on spring boot 3.0.2 to use JWT, but so far, it hasn't worked.

Whenever I start my spring boot API app, none of my endpoints are exposed except /actuator. And I keep getting a default password given to me.

Here's my security config class:

```
    @Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ApiSecurityConfig {
    private final AuthenticationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilter;
private final UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

private final CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint;

@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

    return authenticationProvider;
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
    return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling(e -> e.authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint))
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests
                    .requestMatchers("/merchant/auth/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/swagger-ui.html").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated())
            .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));

    http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    http.addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    return http.build();
}
}
```

EDIT: Here's my authentication token filter:

```
    @Slf4j
@Configuration
public class AuthenticationTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Autowired
    private JwtUtils jwtUtils;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String jwt = "";
        String headerAuthorization = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        if (StringUtils.hasText(headerAuthorization) && headerAuthorization.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            jwt = headerAuthorization.substring(7, headerAuthorization.length());
        }

        try {
            if (!jwt.isEmpty() && jwtUtils.validateJwt(jwt)) {
                String username = jwtUtils.getUsernameFromJwt(jwt);

                UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication =
                        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            } else {
                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
                response.setContentType("application/json");
                response.getWriter().write("{\"status\": \"false\", \"message\": \"Access denied\", \"data\": \"Invalid token\"}");
                response.getWriter().flush();
                return;
            }
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            log.error("Invalid key spec exception thrown:", e);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            log.error("No such algorithm exception thrown:", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: writing custom security is bad practice and you should instead use the built in JWT features of spring security instead of writing your own https://github.com/Tandolf/spring-security-jwt-demo

Comment: I disagree that it's bad practice. Your example is based on the Oauth2 resource server, which I've looked at. The authorization server for generating JWTs requires users to input their credentials in a spring form, and that doesn't work for my use case.

Comment: you can disagree how much you want, but writing a custom security solution, is bad practice as it doesn't not adhere to any current rfc standard. Thats why there are standards, to avoid custom potentially dangerous security solutions. Also, you implementation, will always have to call `userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername` which means you can probably be exposed to DDoS or overload attacks. The whole point of a JWT is that you shouldn't need to to any external lookups, because all the information needed is in the JWT. You have several security issues with this custom implementation.

Comment: I never said this was production level code. I'm trying to experiment with JWT. Also, yes, I will continue to disagree. I refuse to accept that I absolutely have to implement OAUTH2 in order to secure my app just because I want to use JWT. Oauth2 is not a silver bullet for JWT authentication. There are a myriad of ways to code and secure your  app. I get you're a fan of it, and that's fine

Comment: `I'm trying to experiment with JWT.` this is your problem, JWT has NOTHING to do with Oauth2. JWT is a token format. Its one format out of several token formats. Oauth2 is a set of several standards of how to authenticate users, services, applications, mobile apps etc. You can implement oauth2 with opague tokens, baerer tokens, AT tokens, refresh tokens, etc. etc. You are asking how to get JWT authentication to work, and im telling you what you should be learning instead. But dont worry, im not going to write here anymore because you obviously dont want to learn

Comment: I referenced Oauth2 because when you criticised my use of JWT and said I should use the built in JWT features of spring security, you pointed me to a link to your blog where you used Oauth2 resource server as an example of how to effectively use JWT. I'm saying that yes, while that works, it doesn't work for me.

Comment: As said before you dont seem to have any interest in doing things right, saying that ”something doesnt work” with out a proper reason is not an argument. Im telling you that custom security is bad practice. That is a fact. Good luck, you will need it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to to Tangrunze I was able to see that I missed out the filterChain.doFilter(request, response);

But also, I discovered that I had a componentScan annotation in my main class because I was trying to pick up some components in a different maven project.

Apparently, spring security auto configuration kicks in if you scan other base packages before the resident package where your config is in.